# MacOS >11.0: Is there a way to programmatically give an app Privacy->Accessibility Permissions?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, privacy, accessibility

Using only a command line, is it possible to add an app to Security & Privacy/Privacy/Accessibility shown below?

Using Azure Pipelines, I'm attempting to set up a remote machine and it needs a specific app to have these accessibility permissions. I don't have access to the machine, I can only set things up using the command line. Is it possible to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Using the [tccutil](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/01/28/a-guide-to-catalinas-privacy-protection-4-tccutil/) command only allows you to reset the permissions so the user can click and grant permission.

However if the Mac is enrolled in a [Mobile Device Management](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/aside/sec1a32cff88/1/web/1) system, you can create a profile that has the appropriate TCC permissions set and push it out to the device. More information here:

https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2018/08/31/creating-privacy-preferences-policy-control-profiles-for-macos/

Comment: You definitely need an MDM for this.